# HTML5 Flyout Content Blocks?

Tags: html, html5-animation

Someone had to ask it, I've been drooling over it since Microsoft launched http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/

**How in the world are they doing that?**

You know what I mean, the flying, re-arranging content blocks. I know they are doing the site redirecting using the `/#/` URL as a placeholder and then just appending the rest as a link, but I've scoured their source for hours and just cannot for the life of me figure out how they are doing the flying content blocks.

Obviously I cannot copy the source code, but I would love to figure this out - even if I can't use it in production, it's so fascinating to see what we can do without flash that years ago we would have done ONLY in flash, and it would have been clunky at that.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are using Jquery along with a number of other javascript frameworks. They are listed at the bottom of the source file.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's with jQuery, I'm just trying to figure out how.

Comment: jquery.com is a great place to start ;-)